# XSD - The datatype is missing

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd.exe

I have two xml schema files (xsd). One defines a datatype called "Error", the second refers to it.

Here are the schemas:

CreateFolderResult.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="CreateFolderResult"
    targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/dws/"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/dws/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/dws/"
>
  <s:element name="CreateFolderResult">
    <s:complexType>
      <s:choice>
        <s:element name="Result"/>
        <s:element name="Error" type="Error"/>
      </s:choice>
    </s:complexType>
  </s:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Error.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Error"
    targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/dws/"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/dws/"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"           
    xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/dws/"           
>
  <xs:simpleType name="ErrorTypes">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="ServerFailure"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Failed"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="NoAccess"/>    
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="Error">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="ErrorTypes">
          <xs:attribute name="ID">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
                <xs:maxInclusive value="14"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
          <xs:attribute name="AccessUrl" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>  

</xs:schema>
```

These schema files come from this PDF: [MS-DWSS](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/8/858F2155-D48D-4C68-9205-29460FD7698F/%5BMS-DWSS%5D.pdf)

When I try to generate C# classes from them I get an error saying that "The datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/dws/:Error' is missing.

I googled it, and I tried a couple ways how to use xsd.exe properly but still has the same error.

The command I'm using is "xsd.exe /c CreateFolderResult.xsd Error.xsd".

I also created this "installer":

```
<xsd xmlns='http://microsoft.com/dotnet/tools/xsd/'>
  <generateClasses language='CS' namespace='MyNamespace'>    
    <schema>CreateFolderResult.xsd</schema>
    <schema>Error.xsd</schema>
  </generateClasses>
</xsd>
```

And tried to run: "xsd.exe /p:Installer.xsd /c" but didn't work either.
I believe I'm doing something wrong when defining the namespaces.

What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I don't know xsd.exe.

Generally when you want to use types from one schema in another you have to

- [include](http://w3schools.com/schema/el_include.asp) it if the target namespaces are the same
- [import](http://w3schools.com/schema/el_import.asp) it if the target namespaces are different

Comment: @musiKk

I put include in top of the schema but no changes.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="CreateFolderResult">
  <!-- ... -->
  <s:include schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/dws/Error.xsd" />  
  <!-- ... -->
</xs:schema>

Comment: The schema location is invalid.

Comment: @musiKk the schema location is the following: <s:include schemaLocation="h ttp://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/dws/Error.xsd" /> my last comment was truncated, what should I type instead of it?

Comment: If you visit the URL you will see an error. You have to provide a valid address that leads to the schema. The simplest thing is that your schemas are right next to each other. Then the location would simply be the name of the schema (e.g. `schemaLocation="Error.xsd"`).

Comment: @musiKk I couldn't find any other valid URL. It was defined in a PDF written by Microsoft.

Comment: Have you tried what I wrote in my last comment? I don't know if this works (again, I don't work with .Net so I'm just guessing). You can use any URL for `schemaLocation` as long as it's valid. Don't confuse this with namespaces; they are fixed.